# Iframe over Applet

Tags: html, iframe, applet

I want to display rich HTML content on top of my Applet Game. I tried using JeditorPane but its not loading CSS properly.

I know of a hack where iFrame is displayed on top of Flash Player. So is there any such hack where in i can display HTML content on top of my Applet Game?

Comment: Typically people have not been able to get `DIV` elements to appear over the top of an applet. *"I tried using JeditorPane but its not loading CSS properly."*  What CSS specifically?  I have had good use of simple CSS in `JEditorPane`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Article Here](http://www.gobdg.com/blog/2009/04/how-to-show-a-div-over-a-select-box-iframe-flash-java-applet-etc/), it shows how to make a div appear over another set of objects, applying the same logic you can make the div contain a iFrame.